# Can columns with headers be added to reports that are not fields?

Tags: reporting

Is it possible to add Placeholder columns into a Sales force report? These additional columns are not related to fields in SFDC and will not populate with any data in SFDC but will be on the excel spreadsheet when the report is exported. This report is exported daily and we don't want to add the columns/column headers to the expoted report every time.

Comment: Honestly... no. You can make Bucket Fields, but those will show some data (you can't just have it be blank), and you can make Summary Formulas, but those won't appear in all types of exports, which leaves you with ... creating a field.

Comment: you can always use Conga Composer -- the excel template can include blank columns or columns derived from other columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot. The only way I can think of achieving that is to create a new field that will always be empty and add it to the report. This is not really a recommended approach.

To get a similar result (instead of having a blank column, you would have a column that says "Other" in every row), you could use a Bucket Field.

- Create a bucket field by Clicking on the "Add Bucket Field" option on the left pane of the report builder.
- For the source column, pick any text or picklist field. The "Name" field would work fine for any object type.
- Fill the "Bucket Field Name" option with the name you would like on the dummy column.
- Check the "Show unbucketed values as 'Other.'" checkbox at the bottom of the popup window.
- Click Ok.

It would look like this:

[image]

Hopefully this is close enough to what you need.

Comment: Thanks...I didn't think there was a clear cut way to do this. With your potential solution, I assume you would have to clear all the column's contents after each export and add new data?

Comment: Bob, that is correct. Not sure if that helps at all.

Answer (score 0):

I just came across this trying to do the same thing.
I did the following workaround to get what you are looking for.

- I created a bucket field on an existing checkbox field.
- Then I added both Yes and No to Unbucketed Values.  Now the column is always empty.

A little late but hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Another workaround:

Create a bucket field (or many) on any numeric field.
Set the cutoff for the bucket to an out of range number - I used "-1" for a number that will always be positive.

Set the field for <= -1 to "---" (really it could be anything, will never happen)

Set the field for > -1 to "-"

The resulting field will always be "-" which is often interpreted as a blank or empty value in Excel. Space or blank doesn't seem to be allowed. But this was very useful for me.

Repeat as needed -- you can even use the same source field multiple times, but you can't use the same "blank" bucket field more than once.

Answer (score 0):

This is untested but under lightning you can now add row level formulas to a report.

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?language=en_US&type=5&id=reports_formulas_row_level_add.htm

Don't see why you could not just write a formula that returned an empty string and repeat that process for the number of blank cols you wanted to insert.

UPDATE: I have discovered you can frustratingly only add 'one' row level formula per report currently Jan 22